# Multithreaded Qt server not echoing data sent by client

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have a server that can handle multiple threads.  The server starts and listens, but it is having trouble echoing when an incoming connection is pending.

I am using telnet to open the socket and send data to the server.  However, the server only displays that it's listening, but doesn't echo any of the data I type through telnet or signify that there is an incoming connection.  I shut off Windows firewall for private networks and still...nothing.

Also tried seeing if the server error string had anything useful to say, but all it is just an empty string.

This is a complete mystery to me and if anyone had anything constructive to note, it'd be much appreciated.  Code for the thread and server is below.

**server.cpp**

```
#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{

}


void MyServer::StartServer()
{
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,1234))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";
    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor,this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()),thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

**thread.cpp**

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{            this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << socket->errorString();
    //thread starts here
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Starting thread";
        socket = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);
                        connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()),Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client Connected";

    exec();
}

void MyThread::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

     qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

     socket->write(Data);
}

void MyThread::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";

    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `Q_OBJECT` macro in `server.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Qt are you using? In Qt 5, the parameter for the function *incomingConnection* is of type **qintptr** and not **int**. Have a look at the following links:

[incomingConnection - Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection)

[Qt 5 - Multithreaded server tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Multithreaded_Client_Server.php)

Comment: Wow, that totally fixed the problem!  Unfortunately, it's crashing now when I changed the parameter to a qintptr.  Should I change the parameter passed to the Thread constructor to a qintptr as well?

Comment: Yes. Visit the second link I posted in the answer.